# Can't open chrome://something with window.open on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Good evening everyone,

I would like to open a window with javascript code.
Usually `window.open` works fine but the link I provide is `chrome://gpu` and when I do that, Chrome redirects me to the `about:blank` page. It happens only with `chrome://` links, everything else works fine.

I may understand it is some security issue and Chrome blocks these links to be opened. Do you know if there is a workaround or a setting to allow Javascript to open `chrome://` in a new window ?

Thanks a lot,

Clems4ever

Comment: I don't think so. It doesn't work with file:// urls either. What do you want to do that for? A plugin/extension can probably do it.

Comment: Not with Javascript. As stated, you would need to write a Chrome extension.

Comment: Ok thanks guys ! Here we go for an extension then.